# How to pick the year firstly when a angular-ui/bootstrap datepicker popup opened?

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to pick year firstly in datepicker and after that pick month and after that pick day.

**I want to see years first.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
datepickerMode: "year"
```

Comment: thanks ibo but, that is working >>
`datepickerMode: "'year'"`

Answer (score 0):

js

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
datepickerMode: "'year'",
formatYear: 'yy',
startingDay: 1};
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" />
```

This is solution > [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j7DoodFtKLjodJY4jlDY?p=preview)